# How to Fix This Incorrect Resampling?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I'm trying to resample the upcoming DF .

```
Mi_Meteo.head()


     Sensor ID   Time Instant    Measurement
0      14121   2013/11/14 17:00    0.8
1      14121   2013/11/14 18:00    0.6
2      14121   2013/11/14 19:00    0.4
3      14121   2013/11/14 20:00    0.4
4      14121   2013/11/14 21:00    0
```

Here's What I've Done:

```
Mi_Meteo = Mi_Meteo.set_index(['Time Instant']) # to Make The Time Instant as an Index
Mi_Meteo.index = pd.to_datetime(Mi_Meteo.index, errors='coerce') # to convert it to a DateTimeIndex
Mi_Meteo.resample('3H') # to get a temporal range of 3H
```

But Instead Of Getting This :

```
            Time Instant         Sensor ID          Measurement
0         2013/11/14 00:00:00    14121                0.8
1         2013/11/14 03:00:00    14121                0.6
2         2013/11/14 06:00:00    14121                0.4
3         2013/11/14 09:00:00    14121                0.4
4         2013/11/14 12:00:00    14121                 0
```

I get The Same DF With the Exception That now the 'Time Instant ' is The Index :

```
            Time Instant       Sensor ID          Measurement
      0   2013/11/14 17:00       14121                0.8
      1   2013/11/14 18:00       14121                0.6
      2   2013/11/14 19:00       14121                0.4
      3   2013/11/14 20:00       14121                0.4
      4   2013/11/14 21:00       14121                 0
```

Any Suggestions ? , Thank U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected, add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) after aggregate function:

```
df = Mi_Meteo.resample('3H').sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: I'm Sorry to ask again ,  but when resampling the two other columns ( Sensor ID , Measurement) Changed , and i wanted to keep them as they were , any idea how to achieve that ? , Thanks

Comment: @Dimi - sorry, not understand, because if resample get different number of rows like original.

Comment: Oh thank u , i've finallt resolved my issue , many thanks again.

Comment: @Dimi - supeeer, glad can help!